# jquery auto scroll where the current li is

Tags: jquery, css

I have some menu process by ajax dynamic, see below code.

```
ul{width:80px;height:200px;border:1px solid #ccc;list-style:none;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden}
.li{float:left;width:60px;padding:3px 5px;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/20px arial;}
.current{color:#f00}

<ul>
    <li class="li">item1</li>
    <li class="li">item2</li>
    <li class="li">item3</li>
    <li class="li">item4</li>
    <li class="li">item5</li>
    <li class="li">item6</li>
    <li class="li current">item7</li>
    <li class="li">item8</li>
    <li class="li">item9</li>
    <li class="li">item10</li>
    <li class="li">item11</li>
    <li class="li">item12</li>
    <li class="li">item13</li>
    <li class="li">item14</li>
    <li class="li">item15</li>
    <li class="li">item16</li>
    <li class="li">item17</li>
    <li class="li">item18</li>
    <li class="li">item19</li>
    <li class="li">item20</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to fix the current li position like these images (My english not well, screenshot may let you know what i need):

1. if current li position is less than `15`, auto scroll the ul and show current li in the second position of top.

[image]

[image]

2. if currnet li position is less than `14`, auto scroll the ul to the bottom when the page loading (scroll is over).

[image]

But how to make that? first should count how many li in the ul after ajax loading? and how to control the scorll position? here is the demo online. thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/eV7ce/

Comment: I'm trying to understand your explanation and what you're asking for. Please keep revising your English as well. I'll be happy to help!

Comment: What do you mean with "*less than 14*"? Their index in the list?

Comment: @Marlo C, i am tring to auto scroll ul to the position where the current li display in image 1 and image 2

Comment: @Daniel Lisik, Ignore this sentence, I mean if the case like image 3, item 20 is the last one, so do not need like this : http://i.imgur.com/AggYmDP.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scroll to the position of the current list item you can use the `animate()` and `position()` methods:

```
$('ul').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.current').prev().position().top
}, 1000);
```

To get the position of the current list item you can use the `index()` method:

```
var n = $('ul li').index($('.current')) + 1;
```

I'm not quite sure of your logic, but you can play with those two samples to achieve what you want.

Comment: Also, `index()` is zero-based so that's why I'm adding 1.

Comment: thanks but how to do if crruent li is item 17? the right way is http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpy8v.jpg, wrong is http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpy8v.jpg, my update code here: http://jsfiddle.net/eV7ce/1/ but not work. thanks again.

Comment: You posted the same image for right and wrong, I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: sorry, this is wrong case: i.imgur.com/AggYmDP.jpg .

Comment: This issue is that `index()` does not return a DOM element, it returns an integer. So the statement `scrollTop: $('ul li').index(t-7).prev().position().top` will cause an error. Try `scrollTop: $('ul li:nth-child('+(t-7)+')').prev().position().top`.